# Is there anyway I can intercept a new call?

Tags: c#, constructor, metaprogramming

I have a type that I would like to be cached, in that, since it's immutable, if you call `new Foo(1)`, it creates it but also adds that instance to a cache, and if you do it again, you'll just end up with the cached `Foo` with a value of 1.

Somehow this means I need to intercept the call `new <Type>()`, and instead use custom logic.

Is this possible, and if so, how is its performance?

Comment: Lookup the Singleton pattern

Comment: @LucMorin How does that help? The class is not a singleton.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand the question then. If you do, then feel free to provide an answer.

Comment: No, you can't. Unless you make the constructor private and force users to use factory method for creating new objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to modify the compiled IL. It would be hard to implement and unreadable. Anyone who sees `new` expects a new instance to be created.

Better use a static factory method:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static Foo GetInstance(int parameter)
    {
        if (FooCache.IsCached(parameter))
        {
            // return instance from cache
        }
        else
        {
            Foo instance = new Foo(parameter);
            // add to cache
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Foo(int parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

Notice that the constructor is private. The only way to get an instance of this class is to use the factory method.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use the Factory Pattern and a private constructor. The private constructor means no code outside of the class can use `new Foo(1)`, but instead you will write something like `Foo.newFoo(1);`, which will hold the logic to create a new `Foo` or return a cached value.